# How to sort a long data html table with javascript?

Tags: javascript, database, sorting, html-table

I have a problem with coding the sorting code for my database. With few data there is no problem but at this time I have to sort about 4000 data and it lasts about 20s, too long time.
By my check, the operation which lasts too much is insertBefore(...,...) function.
Can you please help me?

```
function sorting(list) {
  var list_data = [];
  var list_id = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
   list_data[i] = Date.parse(list[i].cells[1].innerHTML);
   list_id[i] = parseInt(list[i].cells[12].innerHTML);
  }

//ordino gli array
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < list.length-1; j++) {
   if (list_data[j] > list_data[j+1]) {
     tmp = list_data[j];
     list_data[j] = list_data[j+1];
     list_data[j+1] = tmp;

     tmp = list_id[j];
     list_id[j] = list_id[j+1];
     list_id[j+1] = tmp;
    }
  }
 }
    //ordinato lista_id
    var j = 0;

   for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    j=i;
    while (list_id[i] != parseInt(list[j].cells[12].innerHTML)) {
     j++;
    }
   var target = list[i];
   var newElement = list[j];

   target.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, target);
   }
 }
```

I have my table with 13 columns 0-12. The thirteenth column contains hidden cells with id of the data. I started with a bubblesort and then changed in this because i thought it could work better, but it still lasts 20s to sort. How suggested in comments I'm starting to think that a sort by server is better, but I don't know how to implement

Comment: Provide relevant code with your question so that people can  understand your issue better and provide solutions with better accuracy

Comment: How are you sorting? Do you have a list in memory with the data? Can you sort it on the backend instead?

Comment: I have all data on MySql Database

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the sorting. Created a snippet with time-logging, so you can see that a 5000 items long list's sorting is not that much of a problem.

Try setting up your project so that you control the data & only output the results (the snippet is a very simple example of that).

```js
const tbody = document.getElementById('tbody')
let sortDesc = false

const rowHtml = (rowData) => {
  return `
    <tr>
      <td>
        ${ rowData.first }
      </td>
      <td>
        ${ rowData.second }
      </td>
    </tr>
  `
}

const setTable = (data) => {
  tbody.innerHTML = ''
  tbody.innerHTML = data.map(rowData => {
    return rowHtml(rowData)
  }).join('')
}

const sortData = (data, desc) => {
  return data.sort((a, b) => {
    if (desc) {
      return b.first - a.first
    } else {
      return a.first - b.first
    }
  })
}

renderTable = (data) => {
  console.time('sort data')
  const d = sortData(data, sortDesc)
  console.timeEnd('sort data')
  sortDesc = !sortDesc
  console.time('set table')
  setTable(d)
  console.timeEnd('set table')
}

let data = [];

(function() {
  console.time('create items')
  for (let i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
    data.push({
      first: i,
      second: `${ i }-${ i }`,
    })
  }
  console.timeEnd('create items')
  renderTable(data)
})();

const btnSort = document.getElementById('btnSort')

btnSort.addEventListener('click', function() {
  renderTable(data)
})
```

```html
<button id="btnSort">SORT</button><br />
<table id="table">
  <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
</table>
```

You can see from the time-logs that the real "expensive" stuff is actually putting out the HTML ("set table" in this case takes ~100 times as much time as "sort data").